# web audio api is not supported in this browser

Tags: веб-программирование, аудио, web-audio

При нажатии кнопки Record For 5 Seconds на сайте:
https://demos.subinsb.com/Francium/voice/
у пользователя в браузерах Chrome и Firefox появляется ошибка:
web audio api is not supported in this browser

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: В тексте ошибки и так указана причина, какое слово здесь вам непонятно?

Comment: эти браузеры не поддерживают audio api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке выкидывается файлом [Fr.voice.js](https://lab.subinsb.com/projects/Francium/voice/Fr.voice.js). См. в нём строку 66 с этим сообщением.

Это указывает на то, что пользователь пользуется очень устаревшими обозревателями сети. Современные Chrome и Firefox [давно поддерживают Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

**Решение:** пользователь должен скачать и обновить свои Chrome и Firefox.